# How to get inline keyboard for a previously sent message?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Consider the following sequence:

1. A Telegram bot sends a `Message` with an [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) with `InlineKeyboardMarkup` to a specific `User`
2. When the user hits one of the buttons of an `InlineKeyboardMarkup`, bot receives a response with a [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)
3. `CallbackQuery` contains a `message` object, which represents the original message, which was sent in step 1, but as far as I can see in API docs, [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) does not contain any information about `InlineKeyboardMarkup` or `reply_markup`.

So is it possible to get `InlineKeyboardMarkup` of the originally sent `Message`?
If there is no way of getting it, are there any workarounds in this case?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There have no way to do this

Comment: @Maak I want to modify buttons of the originally sent keyboard, and these changes are based on the original keyboard. To be precise — I need the order of buttons in the original keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update 1 June 2019

Recently [Telegram Bot API developers added](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#may-31-2019) a new field `reply_markup` of type `InlineKeyboardMarkup` to a `Message` object.

So now you can get previously sent keyboard like that: `Update.CallbackQuery.Message.ReplyMarkup`